# Fixing memory issues in instruments

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-management, instruments

In my iPhone app i had found many memory issues while instruments , no issues when analysing . Below are my leaks [image]

where or how i can fix these leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is easy step to find out the leaks in your code.. Just follow these steps one by one with screenshot:

Step1:

[image: Tap on Leaks Tabs]

Step 2:

[image: Select the Call Tree option]

Step3:

[image: Check those option to see the leaks only for your code leaks]

Comment: I cant select any from the call tree all are present as shown but not selectable..